# Есть файл XMLAQuery.xmla который нужно десериализовать в LIST C#. Как это лучше сделать?

Tags: c#, xml, list

Имеется файл XMLAQuery.xmla, который необоходимо десериализовать, и чтобы на выходе метод возвращал следующий список:

```
public class Node
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public List ChildNodes { get; set; }
public List Attributes { get; set; }
public Node()
{
}
public Node(string name, List childNodes, List attributes)
{
Name = name;
ChildNodes = childNodes;
Attributes = attributes;
}
}
public class NodeAttribute
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Посоветуйте, как проще это сделать, потмоу как я пробовал и XmlSerializer, и Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Utils.Deserialize - и каждый раз получаю ошибки, которые не удается исправить.

Comment: http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ - кормите сюда свой xml, сайт вам построит рабочую модель.

Comment: Выскакивала следующая ошибка:
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2), ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <Create xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine'> was not expected at Microsoft.Xml,Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderNode.Read4_Node()

Answer (score 1):

Весьма пространный вопрос. Не понятно что именно у вас не получилось.
В общем случае последовательность следующая:

1. Смотрите структуру файла.
2. На ее основе создаете модель(заготовка которой у вас по всей
   видимости уже имеется) применяя атрибуты [XmlRoot], [XmlElement]
3. Десереализуете XML

Comment: вот именно что полей в документе много. Погуглив немного прояснилась тема: этот файл XMLA Query script, он открывается в Sql Management Studio, и из него по запросу Execute можно создать базу, название базы AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE; Но что мне делать дальше? в sql студии я вижу эту базу, как мне ее подгрузить в visual studio 2015 чтобы раскидать данные по нужных List<>'ах